# Enable, disable NSFetchedResultsController in a background enabled application

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working on a VOIP/Chat application that receives data even while in the background.
I need to disable the `NSFetchedResultsController` when the app is moving to the background to prevent UI changes in the background.
 I do it like this -

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive
{
    [super applicationWillResignActive];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{
      [super applicationDidBecomeActive];
      self.fetchedResultsController.delegate =  self.fetchResultControllerDelegate;
}
```

I have noticed that I don't need to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` when coming back to foreground. (**EDIT** : just to clarify the Core Data DB was updated with new data while the app was in the background and the fetchedResultsController.delegate was nil).
And the table updates itself right after reassigning the  `fetchedResultsController.delegate`.

1. What makes it update, does the `fetchedResultsController` preforms fetch when reassigned ?
2. Are there any pitfalls to this approach that can make a conflict between the `tableView` and the `fetchedResultsController` ?

Thanks

Comment: fetchResultController has delegate witch call every time when ManagedObject get update in value and delegate update your tableView as generally we configure or you can update your data in View

Comment: @Retro Hi, I know that, but the updates where made in the background when the fetchedResultController was nil.

Comment: @shannoga: Perhaps you have something in your view controller (e.g. in viewWill/DidAppear) that triggers a performFetch and reloadData. The FRC does *not* automatically re-fetch when you assign a delegate.

Answer (score 2):

Fetched results controllers provide the following features:

Optionally monitor changes to objects in the associated managed object context, and report changes in the results set to its delegate (see “The Controller’s Delegate”).
Optionally cache the results of its computation so that if the same data is subsequently re-displayed, the work does not have to be repeated (see “The Cache”).
A controller thus effectively has three modes of operation, determined by whether it has a delegate and whether the cache file name is set.

No tracking: the delegate is set to nil.
The controller simply provides access to the data as it was when the fetch was executed.

Memory-only tracking: the delegate is non-nil and the file cache name is set to nil.
The controller monitors objects in its result set and updates section and ordering information in response to relevant changes.

Full persistent tracking: the delegate and the file cache name are non-nil.
The controller monitors objects in its result set and updates section and ordering information in response to relevant changes. The controller maintains a persistent cache of the results of its computation.

Answer (score 0):

> What makes it update, does the fetchedResultsController preforms fetch when reassigned ?

It only does a fetch the first time you create a fetched results controller. After that, it is notified of any change to any object in the database as the changes happen, and evaluates whether to add or remove the object to the list of results. It never does a second fetch (except maybe if you get a low memory warning?).

Fetches are slow, it has to read flash memory and that takes milliseconds. However when an object is being changed, it's in RAM so operations only take nanoseconds. This is why it tries hard not to ever look at the sqlite database.

> Are there any pitfalls to this approach that can make a conflict between the tableView and the fetchedResultsController ?

I'm not sure, maybe. If you haven't found any problems in testing, then I think you should assume it's fine. But be sure to test it again carefully when iOS 8 betas are available mid next year, so you can fix any problems before it's released to the public.

If you're worried about RAM usage, you should destroy the fetched results controller. But beware it will take a fairly significant amount of time to create it again, when the user switches back to your app.